# How to compare textarea

Tags: javascript, html

so basically I have 2 textareas

**original**

```
<textarea id="original">
238e2d079751457785266d20c7a6c27c=AoE
2d6debfef8cc4bd0ad2b0d8310d7abce=Buff
a90e94d629b24ca5bc384abccd88e1e6=Channeling
68072537e0794f59bfe6b7a60cbae650=Dash
0e8264cec48b4be189ce67244cd29cc3=EX
</textarea>
```

and **Modified**

```
<textarea id="mod">
a90e94d629b24ca5bc384abccd88e1e6=Channel5
68072537e0794f59bfe6b7a60cbae650=Dashing through the snow
0e8264cec48b4be189ce67244cd29cc3=EX Dee
</textarea>
```

what I need is code that will compare both IDs(everything before =) and if the id is the same but value(things after =) isnt it will overwrite the value, otherwise it will keep the value.

**ID is never changing!**

result will look like

```
238e2d079751457785266d20c7a6c27c=AoE
2d6debfef8cc4bd0ad2b0d8310d7abce=Buff
a90e94d629b24ca5bc384abccd88e1e6=Channel5
68072537e0794f59bfe6b7a60cbae650=Dashing through the snow
0e8264cec48b4be189ce67244cd29cc3=EX Dee
```

Comment: that's easy but did you tried something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your task in few steps... To make the story short here is working solution, should be clear from the code and comments [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/brootle/587xLrcj/)

What I am doing is this:  1. Convert content of text areas into Objects. 2. Compare Objects. 3. Update content of original text area

```
  // just get elements that we will work with
  var originalTextArea = document.querySelector('#original');

  // 1. split content of text areas into lines
  // 2. make objects with key - value pairs 

  var originalConent = document.querySelector('#original').textContent.split('\n');
  // console.log(originalConent);

  var listOriginal = {};

  originalConent.forEach(line => {
     var key_value = line.split('=');
     // just make sure we don't catch empty line
     if(key_value.length > 1){
       var key = key_value[0];
       var value = key_value[1];
       listOriginal[key] = value;
       // console.log(key_value);
     }
  });

  console.log(listOriginal);

  var modifiedConent = document.querySelector('#mod').textContent.split('\n');
  // console.log(modifiedConent);

  var listModified = {};

  modifiedConent.forEach(line => {
    var key_value = line.split('=');
    // just make sure we don't catch empty line
    if(key_value.length > 1){
      var key = key_value[0];
      var value = key_value[1];
      listModified[key] = value;
      // console.log(key_value);
    }
  });

  console.log(listModified);  

 // 3. check if values in modified are different
 //    if values are different - update them in original objects
 //    update content of text area with original data

document.querySelector('#update').addEventListener('click', updateOriginal);

function updateOriginal(){

  // iterate listModified object and update listOriginal
  for (var key in listModified) {
    // just assing value of modified to original
    // in this case even new key - value pairs will be added
    listOriginal[key] = listModified[key];
  }

  // update data of original text area
  var textData = '';
  for (var key in listOriginal) {
    textData+=`${key}=${listOriginal[key]}\n`;
  }    

  originalTextArea.textContent = textData;
}
```

Comment: just to make sure what does this
`${key}=${listOriginal[key]}\n`
mean is that Regular Expression?
also why did you use .querySelector instead of .getElementById

Comment: You could just do `textData+=key+'='+listOriginal[key]+'\n';` I used that construction just to avoid + and insert variables inside. I used .querySelector as it's a kind of more modern than .getElementById. '\n' is the end of the line.

Comment: What I'm fighting now is that it only works with content filled into textarea in html code but not if you insert it on website side
its my fault i forgot to mention it

Comment: where exactly are you trying to put those keys and values? put it in the post, I will have a look

Comment: Okay i fixed it by myself, the problem was `.QuerySelector` doesnt return live value is I had to replace it with `.getElementById`